# How can I install patches directly in a local server from a central server?

Tags: linux, unix, kernel, patch, yum

Every time we do yum update, so what are the latest pkgs are available will be downloaded into our local server and then we can start installation. Is there any chance to install pkgs directly from central server to local server (without downloading pkgs in local server)?

Comment: You will need to download the packages before installation. Are looking to un-package on the central server and just copy the files to the required directories locally? I may be wrong but I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

At first ,You should make sure your remote source server is configured well ,then you can go to /etc/yum.repos.d to config the file "CentOS-Base.repo"

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?
release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://[**your remote source server**]$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file://[**the path of your gpgkey**]
```

I hope it works to you